# Populate table view cells from XML file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I have an array (quite big), and now i want to populate my table view from specific items from it (for specific key). Please take a look at part of my XML file:

```
</Shops>
    <Architecture>Архитектурные достопримечательности<place>
            <name>Старый английский двор</name>
            <description>Старый английский двор — архитектурно-историческая достопримечательность и музей Москвы (ул. Варварка, д. 4). Памятник гражданской архитектуры XV—XVII веков, резиденция английской торговой Московской компании, а во время посольских миссий — Английский посольский дом.</description>
            <webpage>http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Английский_двор_(Москва)</webpage>
            <latitude>55.752297</latitude>
            <longitude>37.626897</longitude>
            <imageCell>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/gzbgtll5wzn9dox/StaryiAngliskyiDvor.jpg?dl=0</imageCell>
            <imageFirst>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/8abn9c6omb1qp3h/StaryiAngliskyiDvor.jpg?dl=0</imageFirst>
            <imageSecond>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ihrdgys6nr1zsiz/EnglishCourt2.jpg</imageSecond>
            <imageThird>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/yt36zjdc1vqgb1k/EnglishCourt3.jpg</imageThird>
            <imageFourth>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/iu9upggjuafd8y5/EnglishCourt4.jpg</imageFourth>
        </place>
        <place>
            <name>Палаты Романовых</name>
            <description>Палаты Романовых находятся в Зарядье. Зарядье — так в старину называлась часть центра Москвы, расположенная «за рядами» торговых лавок, примыкающих к Кремлю. Район расположен к Востоку от Кремля, между Варварской улицей, в советские времена носившей имя Разина, и Москвой-рекой. Свое название он получил в XVI веке. И сегодня это место в центре Москвы. Палаты Романовых в Зарядье — это единственная постройка, сохранившаяся от большой усадьбы бояр Романовых.</description>
            <webpage>http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Палаты_Романовых</webpage>
            <latitude>55.752717</latitude>
            <longitude>37.629189</longitude>
            <imageCell>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/d9ule0w6ps968ih/PalatiRomanovi.jpg?dl=0</imageCell>
            <imageFirst>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/tmyi71om08fbvhd/PalatiRomanovi.jpg?dl=0</imageFirst>
            <imageSecond>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/bnjjzqhdes7y1wj/PalatiRomanovih2.jpg</imageSecond>
            <imageThird>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/i64yhbwsduk1gem/PalatiRomanovih3.jpg</imageThird>
            <imageFourth>https://dl.dropbox.com/s/thx7en6i157nsng/PalatiRomanovih4.jpg</imageFourth>
        </place>
```

What i want is, for example, populate table view only for items of "Architecture" key. How could i do this?

At now, i do this very straightforward:

```
labelText.text = [[self.listOfPlaceDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Should i specify key in someway? Or separate my XML file for pieces?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse your XML file in order to create an object representation of it.
To do so, you can use the [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/index.html) class ([tuto by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html)), or use a faster library ([look here for a good start](http://jansanchez.com/blog/2013/01/22/state-of-ios-xml-libraries-in-2013/)).

Once you have your object representation, you can use it to fill your tableView.

Comment: I really wonder why there is no simple method, like objectForKey:@"key" and forChildNode:@"Node". XML files a good organised, but it feel painful to work with them.

Answer (score 1):

The first step should be, change your xml to a Property List.(Other option is parse your xml I not recommend).
In new file -> Resource -> You find a blank property list file template.

Comment: I put much effort in that XML file and i think its not reasonable to change it in anyway.. And how property list help? It similar to XML.

Comment: Property list is a XML file, but with some tags than easily convert it to a NSArray or NSDictionary. In your xml the tags are the key, and Parse it (without third part code) is hard work.

Comment: plist files loads very fast while it takes so much more time to parse an XML file.But maybe he can't change his XML into plist because he get it from a webservice.